# Comment not showing on front end

Tags: comments, comment-form, threaded-comments

What would cause a comment to NOT show on the front end when I can see it in the EE control panel?

No errors at all.
Guest can post entries, snaptcha is installed and email isnt required.

site is running on EE 2.5.5, MSM 2.1.3 and using Threaded Comments 2.4.7 (http://dvt.ee/adfZh09)

Have experienced this issue before switching to Threaded Comments with just the native EE comment form and after the switch.

Also experiencing the same comment repeated 2 or 3 times in CP but only one showing on the front end.